# Migration from SVN to GitHub

Tags: git, github, svn, git-svn

I am using git-svn for the migration from SVN to GitHub. Below is how files are structured on the SVN repo, let's called it `projects_repo`

Projects_Repo/

```
- BranchQA_Test/ 

 - project1/
 - project2/
 - project3/
 - project4/

- tags/ 

 - project1/
 - project2/

- trunk/ 

 - project1/
 - project2/
 - project3/
 - project4/
 - project5/
```

I want to migrate **ONLY** **trunk**(master) to GitHub, each project becomes one standalone repo on GitHub, **with** the histories and **without** tags.

So the GitHub will look like:

```
- project1/
- project2/
- project3/
- project4/
- project5/
```

How should I customize the git-svn command? 
Right now I am using the following:

```
git svn clone http://url/svn/projects_repo/ 
    --username $username 
    --authors-file=authors_modified.txt 
    --trunk=trunk/project1/   
    --no-metadata -s project1 `
```

Since the migration consumes lots of time, I want to confirm in advance. Does anyone have an idea whether this is the correct approach?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think the `-s project 1` part is redundant (if not plain wrong) given that you don't want branches or tags (plus they are not where they are normally on a standard svn layout). Try with the command without that part. If you see that git-svn starts fetching revisions from trunk, it means you are done (or very close).

Comment: `-s` is excessive; it means `--stdlayout` i.e. `--trunk/--branches/--tags` — exactly what you're trying to avoid. Everything else looks good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already said in the comments: if you use any of `--{trunk,branches,tags}` — be sure to omit the `-s/--stdlayout`. Although the docs say `--stdlayout` has lower precedence — better be safe than sorry. Because `git-svn` imports do indeed take a lot of time.

[`man 1 git-svn`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn):

> **-T<trunk_subdir> --trunk=<trunk_subdir>**
>   **-t<tags_subdir> --tags=<tags_subdir>**
>   **-b<branches_subdir> --branches=<branches_subdir>**
>   **-s --stdlayout**
>   These are optional command-line options for init. Each of these flags can point
>   to a relative repository path (--tags=project/tags)
>   or a full url (--tags=https://foo.org/project/tags).
>   You can specify more than one --tags and/or --branches options, in case your
>   Subversion repository places tags or branches under multiple paths.
>   The option --stdlayout is a shorthand way of setting trunk,tags,branches
>   as the relative paths, which is the Subversion default.
>   If any of the other options are given as well, they take precedence.